# Why do two minimal polynomials of $\alpha$ over different extensions share the multiplicity of $\alpha$?

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, separable-extension

I am reading [this PDF](https://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/math/MAT4250/h13/separabilitet.pdf) and concerned about **Lemma 3.** I will copy it here for completeness.

> **Lemma 3.** Assume that $K \subseteq E \subseteq L$ is a tower of finite field extensions. If an element $\alpha$ of $L$ is separable over $K$, it is separable over $E$.

> **Proof.** Let $f(x)$ be the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $K$. Then of course $f(x) \in E[x]$, but it is not necessarily irreducible there. We may therefore factor $f(x) = g(x)h(x)$ over $E$, where $g(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $E$ and where $h(\alpha) \neq 0$. Applying the product rule, we find $$f'(x) = g'(x)h(x) + g(x)h'(x)$$
> Hence if $f'(\alpha) = 0$, then $g'(\alpha) = 0$ (since $h(\alpha) \neq 0$ and $g(\alpha) = 0$).

How do we know that $h(\alpha) = 0$? It must be that there is some property of $f$ and $g$ which forces them to have $\alpha$ as a root with equal multiplicity.

I thought for a second that it was perhaps because every minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ has $\alpha$ as a root with multiplicity $1$, but this is not so. Consider any nonperfect field $F$ of characteristic $p > 0$ and take some $\alpha \in F$ that does not have a $p$th root. Then the polynomial

$$f(x) = x^p - \alpha$$

has exactly one root with multiplicity $p$ over its splitting field. So, what else could it be? I've never seen this claim used before and, to be honest, the proof given above seems suspiciously simple.

Also, if this property does hold, I'd appreciate if anyone could given a proof which avoids Galois theory, as I have not yet gotten to that point of study.

Comment: If $\alpha$ is a root of both factors, $g$ and $h$, then it is a root of their GCD. Remember that GCD can be computed by Euclid's algorithm, which results in a polynomial in the same field. That GCD would have smaller degree than $g$. So, that means that $g$ wasn't really the minimal polynomial over $E$, which is a contradiction. Therefore, $h(\alpha)\neq0$.

Comment: Thank you. Does this proof rely in any way on the fact that we're considering finite extensions? It seems that it isn't so.

Comment: Well, only in that if it is not a finite extension maybe an arbitrary element $\alpha$ might not have a minimal polynomial over $K$. But if you know that the element does have it (it is algebraic), then nothing else is needed.

Comment: @user85667 But what if $g = h$? We get $g(x)g'(x) = 0$, but that doesn't allow us to conclude much over a ring. Additionally, $f(x) = g^2(x)$ would clearly be inseparable.

Comment: That's the assumption in the lemma, no?

Comment: Oh, I'm an idiot. I thought this lemma was trying to establish transitivity. Horrible.